# Differentiabilty of this function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I want to show that $(x^2+y^2)^{\alpha}$ is not differentiable for $\alpha\in(0,1)$. All other cases are pretty straightfoward.

Comment: you could add the context, e.g. $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ or in complex spaces?

Comment: Seems like it should be differentiable for $\alpha$ in (1/2,1). This function is radially symmetric, and for such $\alpha$, the outputs taper down to $0$ fast enough as $r\to0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non exstence of partial derivatives are enough to show that the function is not differentiable at $(0, 0)$. Namely,

$f_x(0, 0)=\displaystyle\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(h, 0)-f(0, 0)}{h}=\displaystyle\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{h^\alpha}{h}=\displaystyle\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{h^{1-\alpha}}$ does not exist. Similarly, $f_y(0, 0)$ d.n.e. Of course, instead of $\alpha$ we should have $\alpha/2$ or $\alpha\in(1/2, 1)$.